# time to turn on/off screen from mqtt payload

Tags: python, timer, counter, mqtt, python-multithreading

I am fairly new to python and still learning so please be gentle on me. I have got my python script which subscribes to a MQTT topic and receives a code.

If the payload is equal to that code then it would set the timer which would turn on the display. After the time has elapsed the display would turn off until the payload is again equal to the same code as described previously.

Here is my code:

```
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient
    import time
    from subprocess import call
    from time import sleep


    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    #    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
        client.subscribe("home/OpenMQTTGateway/433toMQTT")
    #def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    #    if msg.topic == 'home/OpenMQTTGateway/433toMQTT':
    #        print(str(msg.payload))


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    global myGlobalMessagePayload
    if msg.topic == 'home/OpenMQTTGateway/433toMQTT':
        myGlobalMessagePayload = msg.payload

    timeUntilDisplayOff = 240

    timer = timeUntilDisplayOff

    while True:

        if msg.payload == '1381683':
                timer = timeUntilDisplayOff
                print ("Motion detected! Setting timer to " + str(timer) + " seconds.")


            if timer > 0:
                    if timer % 10 == 0:
                            print ("Timer: " + str(timer) + " seconds")
                    timer -= 1

            elif timer == 0:
                    call(['vcgencmd', 'display_power', '0'])

                    print ("Timer is 0. Display turned off. Waiting for motion...")
                    # display is now off. we wait for motion and turn it on
                    myGlobalMessagePayload == '1381683'
                    call(['vcgencmd', 'display_power', '1'])
                    timer = timeUntilDisplayOff

            sleep(1)
```

Problem:

When I run my code, I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 26, in <module>
    if msg.payload == '1381683':
NameError: name 'msg' is not defined
```

Also I have used the generic code to repeat the process i.e. near the end after `# display is now off. we wait for motion and turn it on`, does it look correct? or can it be made any better?

Thanks

UPDATE:

So I sorted my code thanks to @blt. However my code keeps on looping when the msg.payload matches '1381683'. I get the following:

```
Motion detected! Setting timer to 240 seconds.
Timer: 240 seconds
Motion detected! Setting timer to 240 seconds.
Timer: 240 seconds
Motion detected! Setting timer to 240 seconds.
Timer: 240 seconds
```

the above keeps on looping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation is important in python.

You need to indent the following block by one level:

```
timeUntilDisplayOff = 1800

timer = timeUntilDisplayOff

while True:
```

Otherwise the code that follows this section will not have the `msg` variable in scope (hence the error).

So the first half of the `on_message` function is:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    global myGlobalMessagePayload
    if msg.topic == 'home/OpenMQTTGateway/433toMQTT':
        myGlobalMessagePayload = msg.payload

    timeUntilDisplayOff = 1800

    timer = timeUntilDisplayOff

    while True:

        if msg.payload == '1381683':
                timer = timeUntilDisplayOff
                print ("Motion detected! Setting timer to " + str(timer) + " seconds.")
```

Comment: did you mean:
    `timeUntilDisplayOff = 1800
    timer = timeUntilDisplayOff
    while True:`

Comment: I mean - add 4 spaces in beginning of each of these three lines so that they are vertically aligned with the beginning of the `if` statement above it.

Comment: ok that works fine thanks for that. 

However I tried the timer to 10 seconds but the problem I am having is that the screen keeps on turning on after 10 seconds regardless of  msg.payload = 1381683. 

I was hoping it would wait for the code to be transmitted and then turn the screen on?

Comment: I can only surmise that you need to move the `call(['vcgencmd', 'display_power', '1'])` to when motion is detected instead of presumably turning it on when the timer period has expired.

Comment: so I tried that but I think in my code the timer isnt working as it keeps on looping beyond 10 seconds. it keeps on printing `Motion detected! Setting timer to 10 seconds`

Comment: You need to indent the if statements in your while loop by the same amount. I recommend that you read up on indentation in python. See https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html?highlight=indentation#id2 as a starting point.